# CSS - Links don't line up properly

Tags: html, css

I am not much of a web designer, more of a backend developer. However, the frontend designer left me with a problem I am facing. I have a login and register links and navigation links on the right. I want these links to line up and display in the same navigation bar. At the moment, my links are distorted. They appear in the middle of the page I am dealing with. I want the login/register links to align to the left side of the navigation bar and I also want the right navigation tp sit within the main navigation. Neither of these things are happening (screenshot provided). how do I get th e user links to align to the left of the top navigation bar an the other links to stay to the right?

Here is a link to my screenshot: https://s30.postimg.org/tlkvrcv5t/Screen_Shot_2017_01_05_at_11_11_55_AM.png

and here is my code:

app.blade.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{!! asset('css/stylesheet.css') !!}" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="mainheader">
    <div class="subcontainer">
        <div class="subcontainer-left">
            <div class="subcontainter-title">Cryptoflip</div>

                @if (Auth::guest())
                <div class="subcontainer-button">
                    <a href="/login">Login</a>
                </div>
            <div class="subcontainer-button">

                <a href="/register">Register</a>
            </div>
                   @else
                    <div class="subcontainer-button">
                <a href="/user/{{$user->name}}"Your Profile</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="subcontainer-button">
                        <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
                    </div>
                    @endif

        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="subcontainer-right noselect">
            <div class="subcontainer-button">
                <a href="support.html">Support</a>
            </div>
            <div class="subcontainer-button">
                <a>Provably Fair</a>
            </div>
            <div class="subcontainer-button">
                <a>Dice</a>
            </div>
            <div class="subcontainer-button bt-active">
                <a href="main.html">Coinflip</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Decoration -->
    <!--<div style="height: 10px; width: 200px; margin: auto; margin-top: -50px; background-color: gold"></div>-->
</div>
<div class="maincontainer">
    @yield('content')

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

stylesheet.css;

```
@font-face {
  font-family: NexaBold;
  src: url(NexaBold.otf); }

@font-face {
  font-family: NexaLight;
  src: url(NexaLight.otf); }

@font-face {
  font-family: OpenSans;
  src: url(OpenSans-Regular.ttf); }

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ecf0f1; }

.mainheader {
  height: 75px;
  font-family: NexaBold;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #dce0e1; }

.menu {
  height: 40px; }

.subcontainer-left {
  height: 75px;
  float: left; }

.subcontainer {
  height: 75px;
  margin: auto; }

.subcontainer-right {
  height: 75px;
  width: auto;
  float: right; }

.subcontainer-button {
  height: 75px;
  width: 100px;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-family: OpenSans;
  font-size: 14px; }

.subcontainer-button a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black; }

.subcontainer-button a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black; }

.subcontainer-button a:active {
  color: black; }

.subcontainer-button a:hover {
  border-bottom: 3px solid gray;
  cursor: pointer; }

.subcontainer-title {
  height: 75px;

  float: left;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-family: OpenSans;
  font-size: 14px; }

.bt-active a {
  border-bottom: 3px solid gold; }

.noselect {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none; }

.maincontainer {
  height: 700px; }

.textheader {
  height: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 180px;
  font-family: NexaLight;
  font-size: 48px; }

.ongoing-header {
  width: 700px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 70px;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #bcc0c1; }

.subheader {
  height: 70px;
  width: 260px;
  font-family: OpenSans;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 70px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: left; }

.subheader-menu {
  height: 36px;
  background-color: #ccd0d1; }

.button {
  height: 36px;
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 36px;
  font-family: OpenSans;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: 0.3s; }

.button:hover {
  background-color: #ecf0f1; }

.subheader-right {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 16px;
  width: 260px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-right: 24px; }

.ongoing-container {
  width: 700px;
  margin: auto; }

.ongoing-game {
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: OpenSans;
  transition: 0.3s; }

.ongoing-game:nth-child(even):hover {
  background-color: #f3f9fa; }

.ongoing-game:nth-child(odd):hover {
  background-color: #f3f9fa; }

.ongoing-game:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #d3d9da; }

.ongoing-game:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #dce0e1; }

.iconholder {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-right: 4px; }

#username {
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  width: 220px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 24px; }

#btcamount {
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  width: 220px;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 24px; }

#ongoing {
  height: 40px;
  width: 212px;
  float: left; }

.bitcoinlogo {
  height: 15px; }

.helpcontainer {
  height: 600px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: OpenSans; }

.helpform {
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 400px;
  font-size: 12px; }

.helpform textarea {
  resize: none;
  font-family: OpenSans; }

#issuetext {
  height: 100px;
  width: 480px; }

#emailtext {
  height: 18px;
  width: 220px;
  font-family: OpenSans; }

.submitbutton {
  height: 40px;
  width: 180px;
  float: none;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: 0.2s background-color; }

.submitbutton:hover {
  background-color: lightgrey; }
```

/*# sourceMappingURL=stylesheet.css.map */

EDIT:Updated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of width on `.subcontainer-left`. Then give a width to `.subcontainer-button`.

```
.subcontainer-left {
    height: 75px;
    /* width: 200px; */
    float: left;
}

.subcontainer-button {
    height: 75px;
    width: 100px;
    ...
}
```

Comment: okay. I comboned both answers above and now my display looks like this (https://s28.postimg.org/vk4grts3h/Screen_Shot_2017_01_05_at_3_33_32_PM.png). I need the cryptoflip text to line up with the links under it on the same row. Thanks for the help so far, i beginning to get the hang of it. i updated the source code in my original question.

Comment: Okay. if i get rid of the suggestion in the answer above the register and lon links align correctly. however the right navbar does not lone up at all. It appears on the next row.

Comment: Can you show a new screenshot, update your markup in question or throw this up online somewhere?

Comment: Add float:left to .subcontainter-title. And give .subcontainer-left width of 100%. https://jsfiddle.net/pahcggoj/1/

Comment: I checked yopur JSfiddle and the design is still off. All of the links are supposed to be on the same row as the Cryptoflip text on the top. login and register right next to the title, and the nav links on the right.

Comment: Right now Login and register appear at the right and the nav links underneath https://s30.postimg.org/qycssgnip/Screen_Shot_2017_01_05_at_5_00_29_PM.png

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pahcggoj/2/ you should be able to take it from here

Comment: great! Thank you! I will work the rest out on my own., I will accept this answer,

Answer (score 0):

You need to place "Cryptoflip" inside a div, for example "subcontainer-title":

```
<div class="subcontainer">
        <div class="subcontainer-left">
            <div class="subcontainer-title">Cryptoflip</div>
                <div class="subcontainer-button">
                    <a href="/login">Login</a>
                </div>
            <div class="subcontainer-button">

                <a href="/register">Register</a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Then add the style for it copying ".subcontainer-button" and modify the content to match what you want it to look (float: left in first place):

```
.subcontainer-title {
  height: 75px;
  width: auto;
  float: left;

  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;

  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 75px;

  font-family: OpenSans;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

And change the width of subcontainer-left:

```
.subcontainer-left {
  height: 75px;
  width: 400px;
  float: left;
}
```